# How to detect if user's account on Metamask is disconnected in frontend

Tags: web3js, metamask, ethers.js, react

am trying to build a web3 application. In my frontend I want to detect if user changed his account on Metamask wallet or disconnected and want to show this change on frontend. How can I do so?

```
  const [account, setaccount] = useState('0x0');
  window.ethereum.on('accountsChanged',async (accounts) =>{
    const changedAccounts =await window.ethereum.request({method: 'eth_requestAccounts'});
    setaccount(changedAccounts[0]);
    console.log('changedAccounts')
  })
  useEffect(async () => {
    if(!window.ethereum){
      window.alert('Please consider installing Metamask');
    }else{
      const accounts =await window.ethereum.request({method: 'eth_requestAccounts'});
      setaccount(accounts[0]);
    }
    if(!window.ethereum.isConnected()){
      console.log('Disconnected')
    }else{
      console.log('Connected')
    }
    console.log('useEffect')
  }, [account]);
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are more events to listen to cover all use cases. In addition, the event subscription and cleanup should be moved into a `useEffect` in order to stop memory leaks.

This is an example that might get you started...

```
const [account, setaccount] = useState('0x0');
useEffect(() => {
  if (!window.ethereum) {
    // Nothing to do here... no ethereum provider found
    return;
  }
  const accountWasChanged = (accounts) => {
    setaccount(accounts[0]);
    console.log('accountWasChanged');
  }
  const getAndSetAccount = async () => {
    const changedAccounts = await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
    setaccount(changedAccounts[0]);
    console.log('getAndSetAccount');
  }
  const clearAccount = () => {
    setaccount('0x0');
    console.log('clearAccount');
  };
  window.ethereum.on('accountsChanged', accountWasChanged);
  window.ethereum.on('connect', getAndSetAccount);
  window.ethereum.on('disconnect', clearAccount);
  window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' }).then(accounts => {
    console.log('accounts', accounts);
    // No need to set account here, it will be set by the event listener
  }, error => {
    // Handle any UI for errors here, e.g. network error, rejected request, etc.
    // Set state as needed 
  })
  return () => {
    // Return function of a non-async useEffect will clean up on component leaving screen, or from re-reneder to due dependency change
    window.ethereum.off('accountsChanged', accountWasChanged);
    window.ethereum.off('connect', getAndSetAccount);
    window.ethereum.off('disconnect', clearAccount);
  }
}, [/* empty array to avoid re-request on every render, but if you have state related to a connect button, put here */]);
```

Comment: But if I connect two or more accounts to the website and then disconnect the one that is currently active. Then the state `account` be equal to the other connected account and that will be reflected on the frontend. Even though we disconnected current account. How to handle this case?

Comment: You will receive a `accountsChanged` event that you can handle to update your application state